# I bought minecraft PC yesterday and none of the servers are showing up or connecting.

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I bought minecraft yesterday and every time I go to play online, it says it "can't reach server" or "failed to reach server" or something of that nature. I know it's not my internet connection because both my WiFi and Ethernet are running awesome, and I took the firewall off of the game. I've tried making my own server and it won't connect to that either. I'm getting kind of frustrated because it's an expensive game to not have work properly. does anybody have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you added the addresses to whichever servers you wish to play?  Unless this has changed recently (I haven't updated to the 1.7 version yet), you have to manually add the addresses yourself.

Comment: Are you playing on the right version for the server you're trying to join?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you are typing into the server connect dialogue? For info, it's always worth quoting the exact error message rather than giving 'something like' what it said, as the detail can sometimes be important.

Answer (score 3):

the game does work fine. I've been playing since early 2010 with no problems, you need to make sure that the server is ONLINE as well, as they are hosted by a physical server.

Checkout these big servers (Which are always online):
hivemc.eu
mc.hypixel.net
(To add them go to your multiplayer server list and click 'add server' and type one of those domains in)

If those appears are offline to you, then it is 100% a problem with either your connection or firewall, hope I solved your problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

When typing in the IP/address to a server, make sure you don't have `http://`, `https://`, or any `/`. So instead of `http://play.example.com/`, do `play.example.com` instead. Or instead of `http://12.34.56.78/` do just `12.34.56.78`.

If a server does not use the default port (which is 25565), put a `:12345` at the end, replacing the 12345 with whatever the port number is. And finally if you're connecting to your own hosted server, use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

And just to be sure, verify you're putting this in the field marked "Server Address".